# How to check if a string contains an element from a list

Tags: apex, string, contains

What is the best way to check if a string contains an element from a list?

for example:

```
String email= 'itairu@gmail.com'
List<String> domainNames = split by ; from domains in a custom setting
```

for example : `(domainNames = [0] - gmail.com, [1] - example.com, [2] - mof.com);`

How can I check if email field is contains one of the values in the domainName's  List?

I can do it with a Boolean field that will be turned to true if one of field is found for this case -

```
boolean found = false;
for(String s : domainNames ){
 if(email.contains(s)){
   found =true;  
 }

}
```

I want to know if there is a better way - in case I will have a huge amount of values to move on in the for loop for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A shorter version of your code just checks the domain directly:

```
Boolean found = domainNames.contains(email.split('@',2)[1]);
```

There's other ways to do this, too, but this is probably the most straightforward version.

Answer (score 4):

If you have control over the type of `domainNames`, you should consider changing its type to [`Set<string>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm).  Sets hash their values, so checking whether they contain a particular value takes the same amount of time regardless of the number of elements in the set, compared to a `List` which must go through each element until it finds one that matches.

```
Set<String> domainNames = new Set<String>{'example.com', 'gmail.com'};
domainNames.contains(email.split('@', 2)[1]);
```

Also, the general solution to the question of whether a particular string contains any strings in a list where they could be in any part of the input string would be to do what you did, except you would use a `break` statement to end the loop once you've found a match:

```
boolean found = false;
for(String s : domainNames ){
     if(email.contains(s)){
         found = true;  
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Both of the answers helped me but unfortunately, I can give the best answer only to one.

Answer (score 0):

in general:

any list that you want to check that at least one of the items contains in a string you can create a util function.

```
Assert.isTrue(ApxUtil.itemListInString('My test', new List<String>{'test'}));
Assert.isTrue(ApxUtil.itemListInString('My test', new List<String>{'other'}));

public static Boolean itemListInString(String val, List<String> items){
        if(String.isBlank(val))return false;
        for(String item : values){
            if(val.contains(item)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```